# Power BI dashboard with reports based on a push dataset do not alwasy update regularly

Tags: powerbi

I have written a little C# program which pushes data to a a streaming push dataset on Power BI Service.  I have a report with a couple of simple visuals (nothing fancy) which are in turn pinned to a dashboard.

About half the time I open the dashboard the Dashboard updates every few seconds.  But half the time it does not update at all and is laggy even if I push the refresh button.

Why is it inconsistent?  I know the data pusher is running as I can refresh the base report and see the new data points come in.

What is it that I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: At a guess you are running in shared capacity (not paid dedicated) so possibly it's not keeping up to a minimum SLA

Comment: I am currently running in a Power BI trial, which would be equal to having a PPU (Premium) license.